# Setting the POSIXct time zone in lubridate::interval()

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a data set, `rfm`, which has a column named `cohort`, of class `Date` as shown below. I also have a vector of calendar dates, rather cleverly named `dates`, whose elements are also of class `Date`:

```
> class(rfm)
[1] "tbl_df"     "data.frame"
> class(rfm$cohort)
[1] "Date"
> class(dates)
[1] "Date"
```

Both `rfm$cohort` and `dates` show the date of the first of the month over a certain time period, with the possibility that `dates` covers a more recent set of months. My problem is simple: I just want to see how many months there are between `max(rfm$cohort)` and `max(dates)`.

The [`lubridate`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/) package makes this easy with the `interval()` function, but the arguments of that function must be `POSIXct`, not `Date` objects:

```
> as.period(interval(ymd(as.character(max(rfm$cohort))),ymd(as.character(max(dates)))), months)
[1] "1m 0d 0H 0M 0S"
```

But do I really need a chained call to `ymd()` and `as.character()`? Wouldn't `as.POSIXct()` suffice? Here's a try:

```
> as.period(interval(as.POSIXct(max(rfm$cohort), tz = 'GMT'),as.POSIXct(max(dates), tz = 'GMT')), months)
Error in while (any(start + est * per < end)) est[start + est * per <  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

This didn't work. It seems that `lubridate` wants me to set the time zone for the interval, not separately for its ends. Like this:

```
> as.period(interval(as.POSIXct(max(rfm$cohort)),as.POSIXct(max(dates)), tz = 'GMT'), months)
[1] "1m 0d 0H 0M 0S"
```

I know that this is less typing, so I should just do what `lubridate` wants, but why wouldn't setting the time zone of interval ends separately also work? By my reading of it, `?interval` suggests that the third argument of this function, `tzone`, should default to getting its value from the time zone of the first. Somehow `as.POSIXct()` won't reveal the time zone to `interval()`, even if it's explicitly set in the same call. What am I missing?

Comment: Odd. What happens if you convert your Dates to POSIXct first, then just do math on them. It works for me without needing to set a tz, e.g. `as.period(rfm$cohort-dates, months)` which yields me a vector of periods.

Comment: `as.period(interval(max(rfm$cohort), max(dates)), months)` seems to work over here with no conversion needed. It gives some warning about factors that I don't understand, but it gives an expected result.

Comment: Neither of the above works for me. Here's Shawn Mehan's solution: `> cmax <- as.POSIXct(max(rfm$cohort))
> dmax <- as.POSIXct(max(dates))
> as.period(interval(cmax, dmax), months)
Error in while (any(start + est * per < end)) est[start + est * per <  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` and doing `> as.period(interval(max(rfm$cohort), max(dates)), months)
Error in while (any(start + est * per < end)) est[start + est * per <  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` gets me the same error.